# Can not configure which Typescript compiler to use in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I am installing Microsoft.TypeScript.MsBuild 2.0.3 NuGet package. This comes with the appropriate tsc.exe in its tools subfolder.
After installing the nuget package my .csproj file contains the line:

```
  <Import Project="..\..\lib\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.0.3\build\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.props" Condition="Exists('..\..\lib\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.0.3\build\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.props')" />
```

*Note: the ..\..\lib folder is correct, that is my package folder.*

It seems all correct (except the minor trap, that Microsoft.TypeScript.targets file shipped with the package contains invalid vstsc parameter (output folder). 
This gives build error, which  proves that this msbuild task is in effect. After correcting this annoying bug (which will arise always when refreshing packages) build is successful.

**However...**

Using SysInternals processexplorer I see that not the installed (NuGet) tsc.exe is called, instead this one:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.8\tsc.exe

Wby... ?. How to configure my project (preferably with NuGet) to use the tsc.exe I want?

Comment: Any luck with this? I thought I had the same problem. What you describe works for me. Did you check both you're props and targets? I have an issue with Intellisense continuing to use the installed version rather than the NuGet version of tsc. edit - Just noticed you are using 2.0.3. This version had some issues, have you tried again with 2.0.6? That works for me.

Answer (score 1):

All I did  to create above mess is...

1. Installing visual studio 2017 while working on visual studio 2015.
2. And I stopped the visual studio 2017 installation as I thought I would  do it in another day.

So the setup application has removed my installed typescript  plugin.  All you have to do is
install type script for Visual Studio 2015. You can download the setup from bellow link.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I create a demo and reproduce your issue on our side.  If you want to use C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.8\tsc.exe, please refer to the following steps.

1.Right-Click -> Unload Project

2.Right-Click -> Edit

3. replace references to

Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props
The import should look something like:

```
<Import
Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props"
Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props')" />
```

Microsoft.TypeScript.targets
The import should look something like:

```
<Import
Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets"
Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets')" />
```

[image]

For more information, please refer to:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Configuring-MSBuild-projects-to-use-NuGet

Comment: a bit confused. I would like to use the installed new tsc included in the NuGet package. My problem that it is NOT used.

Comment: I am a little late to party but can I configure Visual Studio 17 to use specific tsc without changing the .csproj file?